# How I can take backup of selected Procedures or Functions from Oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, backup, expdp

I want to save selected procedures and functions for backup purposes in .prc file format. As of now I am doing this manually by the help of PLSQL Developer.

I have found some solutions, but none worked for me. Here is an example.

1. expdp schemas=Test, include= procedure like 'abc%';

and here is the error while executing the above script.

**SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "expdp sche..." - rest of line ignored.**

Please help me if there is any way to automate this manual effort.

Comment: You can't run data pump commands from PLSQL Developer. You can use a plsql block of code to create a data pump job and execute it though. I would also hope that you have a file based source control versioning system that you keep all of your PL/SQL in.

Comment: At your server or client command line, you can do "exp username/password owner=test rows=n" and this will backup all your objects, but not the data.

Answer (score 0):

### you can try this

```
 SELECT TEXT FROM
 ALL_SOURCE 
 WHERE NAME LIKE '%abc%'
 TYPE='PACKAGE BODY'
 ORDER BY LINE
```

### distinct type

> PROCEDURE , PACKAGE  ,PACKAGE BODY, TYPE BODY, TRIGGER ,FUNCTION ,TYPE

Comment: what u mean , command not found, which editor you try this code on

Comment: I am using PL/SQL developer

Comment: ORA:00933:SQL command not properly ended . this is the error.

Comment: SELECT TEXT FROM
 ALL_SOURCE 
 WHERE NAME LIKE 'USPX%'
 TYPE='PROCEDURE'
 ORDER BY LINE